# InstaBug 4.12.1 not recording crashes on Android

Tags: instabug

We're using the 4.12.1 version of the InstaBug SDK and set up the SDK according to their official documentation.

All the other features are functional(bug report, improvement report, video capture, chat, surveys) but the crash reporting feature is the only one not recording a thing on the dashboard.

We did force enabled crash reporting although it seems like it is enabled by default.

```
new Instabug.Builder(this, "APP_TOKEN")
.setCrashReportingState(Feature.State.ENABLED)
.build();
```

We also use Crashlytics for crash reports but according to their documentation, that's okay as long as InstaBug is the last one initialised.

Does this ring a bell to anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the tools works, but it takes **more than 1 hour** for the dashboard to update. The rest of the features are very responsive on the dashboard and this caused the confusion.

*Not sure if I should keep this question or delete it...I couldn't find anything online about it, so I posted it here. Maybe it could help others?*